# Request: dashdb as synonym for db2-luw

Tags: support, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

An IBM Cloud database system, based on Db2 LUW, was named dashDB. [It has been rebranded to Db2 Warehouse on Cloud and Db2 on Cloud](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/06/ibm-dashdb-transactions-db2-cloud-renamed/). I would like to suggest [dashdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dashdb) as a synonym for [db2-luw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/db2-luw). Also note that the former dashDB Local is now branded Db2 Warehouse.

However, I get the error

> Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators

Is this caused by the two in the name...?

How do I proceed?

There is also the tag [db2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/db2) (**ibm-db2**) which refers to the products on the mainframe, midrange and on Linux, UNIX, and Windows.

Comment: Very unfamiliar with the technologies here, but as dashDB is *based* on Db2 LUW, should we really consider them to be the same product via a synonym? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: There are different deployed versions of Db2 LUW, different feature sets. They are all Db2 LUW, use the same client SDKs and drivers and share the same documentation. Thus, it should be a synonym.

Comment: I disagree. Basically [tag:dashdb] is a subset of [tag:db2-luw], but specifically for questions related to the cloud version. It's similar to how [tag:db2-luw] is a subset of [tag:db2]. In my opinion, I do think that [tag:dashdb] warrants it own tag, and if anything should happen, it should be a rename of the tag [tag:dashdb] to [tag:db2-cloud] or something similar.

Comment: First, the name dashdb is not in use anymore. Second, the former "dashDB Local" is now "Db2 Warehouse", the service "dashDB" now "Db2 Warehouse on Cloud". Thus, renaming dashdb to db2-cloud would misrepresent the "dashDB Local" / "Db2 Warehouse" scenarios. dashDB is just one way of deploying db2-luw.